# Parse json data image to image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

This is my JSON response,

```
 {
        "AppConfig": {
            "store_logo": "url",
            "deal_status": "A",
            "see_the_menu_btn": "A",
            "store_id": "3",
            "store_name": "  Pizza Restaurant",
            "bg_image": "www.my image.png"
        }
    }

 NSString *localwthr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my url"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:localwthr]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    if (responsedata) {
        NSDictionary *Dictionarydetails = [NSJSONSerialization
                                           JSONObjectWithData:responsedata
                                           options:kNilOptions
                                           error:nil];
        NSLog(@"The return data is: %@",Dictionarydetails);

        NSString *imgURL=[[Dictionarydetails objectForKey:@"AppConfig"]objectForKey:@"bg_image"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imgURL]]];
    }
}
```

I need to get URL value for key `bg_image`, download image and set it in the `UIImageView`. How can I do this?

Comment: Post the code you have so far to accomplish what you need.

Comment: NSString *localwthr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"my url"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:localwthr]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

Comment: OK, you posted the code. What's wrong? You don't tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

imageUrl is never like "www.my image.png",
imageUrl is like "http://www.serverName.com/directory/..../imageName.png"

if there is space in your url then you have to convert it into UTF8 format, which is a standard format for webURL.
so You should use,

```
imgURL = [imgURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Use it as it shown in below code.

NSString *imgURL=[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"AppConfig"]objectForKey:@"bg_image"];
    imgURL = [imgURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imgURL]]];
```

cheers!

Comment: then you should convert it in the UTF8 format by using the line below,imgURL = [imgURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Answer (score 1):

For **loading the image from the URL**, then

```
NSString *imgURL=[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"AppConfig"]objectForKey:@"bg_image"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imgURL]]];
```

Comment: I'm agree with you, but you need first deserialize the json content with NSJSONSerialization object

Comment: jsonDict is already a object of NSJSONSerialization. That's the primary part .

Answer (score 0):

check out this code , is this you are needed or not as rmaddy told post your done code as far as now

```
NSString *imageName=[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"AppConfig"]objectForKey:@"bg_image"];
imageview.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imageName]]];
```

Comment: It won't work for the Url based image ..**UIImage imageNamed** for the local directories.

Comment: @KumarKl ya its correct , but he has not mentioned about the image URL in it , so i have just mentioned the code to get the URL from the json dictionary and use it in uiimageview

Comment: my url is advantixcrm.com/prj/mitech/images/bg_images/blacktheme.png

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSString *imgURL=[[jsonDict objectForKey:@"AppConfig"]objectForKey:@"bg_image"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imgURL]]];
```